# Batch script pauses on exception, possible to continue automatically?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following snippet in a batch file to run a program with an argument in a loop:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (some-list.txt) do (
    java -jar some-java-package.jar com.example.package.class %%a
)
```

Sometimes the Java application crashes on a *memory exception* (this could be an important point, because according to my current programming experience these seem to be special exceptions and I was not able to catch them like I would catch normal exceptions in program code).

In such a case it seems my batch script pauses until I take action: I can press `Ctrl-C` and on batch's question if I want to stop the batch job respond `N`, then it will continue with the next program call.

Is it possible to tell batch to go on in such events automatically?

Comment: Have you tried to call the Java command line using the `start` command?

Comment: `start` seems to lead to parallel execution, which is a problem, because the command modifies files.

Comment: I guess you omitted the `/WAIT` switch; `start "" /WAIT "app"` waits for `app` to finish execution; type `start /?` to get more information...

Comment: Thanks, I'd say that's running. Reduced java heap space to 1M. It's throwing exceptions and starting the next job. You could add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `java` using the `start` command like this:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (some-list.txt) do (
    start "" /WAIT "java" -jar some-java-package.jar com.example.package.class %%a
)
```

The `/WAIT` switch lets `start` wait until the application (`java`) has finished execution.
The `""` portion defines the window title (this is defined here since `start` sometimes confuses it with the command line when no title given).

Comment: You have to omit the quotation marks around the command to be executed. Cannot find it in the official documentation, but it's stated on [robvanderwoude.com](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/start.php): "Don't forget to enclose whatever you start in quotes if the string contains spaces (*unless these spaces separate the "command" from its parameters*)."

Comment: Ah yes; I edited my answer accordingly, thanks for the hint! I added quotes around the application `java` itself, just for demonstration, so this might be used also for programs which have spaces in their names...